# PostgreSQL: sub-queries and aggregate functions(Sum)

Tags: sql, postgresql

I tried referring to other questions; I've inferred that sub-queries cannot be used on aggregate functions, but I cannot solve this use case.

```
Tables:  
1. CustomerInfo(c_id,name)  
2. ProductInfo(p_id,price)  
3. ModelInfo(p_id,m_id,name)  
4. PurchaseRecords(c_id,m_id,quantity)
```

Required output:
List of customer names, with total amount purchased by each customer.

My flow of thought is that:
Link PurchaseRecords with ModelInfo to get `p_id`,
ModelInfo with ProductInfo to get the price,
Multiply price returned by quantity in PurchaseRecords for every specific customer,
which requires me to link CustomerInfo in the end to get the name.

I'm using Postgres. I could write a program for that in Java, but I find it hard to do it with SQL. So, what is the correct query here? Any pointers on how to think problems out are appreciated!

Comment: To make things easier to answer you really should build a schema, with sample data and an expected output based on that. Perhaps using [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17) or a similar tool.

Comment: I did it on pgAdmin 4 with sample data; how do I share it here? Thanks!

Comment: You could use [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17). Don't forget to edit your question adding its link. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  c.name as customer_name,
  sum(coalesce(p.price, 0) * coalesce(pr.quantity, 0)) as amount_purchased
from
  CustomerInfo c
  left join PurchaseRecords pr on c.c_id = pr.c_id
  left join ModelInfo mi on mi.m_id = pr.m_id
  left join ProductInfo p on p.p_id = mi.p_id
group by
  c.name
```